# beautifulsoup finding largest product image

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver

driver= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_PATH)
driver.get('https://www.childrensalon.com/artesania-granlei-blue-knit-dungaree-shorts-set-313840.html')
soup = bs(driver.page_source,'lxml')
```

what I have tried to get the images ordered in their largest size

```
#images=[i.get_attribute('data-hrefx2') for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@data-hrefx2 and @data-href and @class="img j-zoom-link"]')]
#images = [i.get_attribute('data-href') for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="slides"]/li/span')]
```

How can I get the Largest images in the same order as the website shows them ?

Excepted output

```
images = ['https://cdn.childrensalon.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/image/1000x1000/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/a/r/artesania-granlei-blue-knit-dungaree-shorts-set-313840-ca99037b559a330e34edd556e75288c394e51d8a.jpg','https://cdn.childrensalon.com/media/catalog/product/cache/0/image/1000x1000/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/a/r/artesania-granlei-blue-knit-dungaree-shorts-set-313840-271714b31b5652e4f8eebd659fd97dcd73af46b5-outfit.jpg',...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
imgs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]//li/span/img")
for img in imgs:
    a = img.get_attribute('data-src')
    print(str(a).replace('small_image', 'image').replace('256x256', '1000x1000'))
```

The picture is actually the same but calling "small image", "256x256" format

`.replace('small_image', 'image')` ("small image" to "image")

`.replace('256x256', '1000x1000')` ("256x256" to "1000x1000")

the problem will be solved when we call as